# Terraform: Workaround for aws S3 RTC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am using Terraform version 1.0.5. I would like to enable aws S3's RTC for S3 buckets created using my Terraform script. As Terraform does not offer the ability to enable/disable RTC yet (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10974), I was thinking of using a local-exec provisioner to update replication config of the created buckets (see below).

```
resource "null_resource" "s3_bucket" {
  depends_on = [
    # a module that creates S3 buckets
  ]
  triggers = {
    # below statement makes sure the local-exec provisioner is invoked on every run
    always_run = timestamp()
    encoded_replication_config = local.replication_config
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket '${primary_bucket_name}' --replication-configuration '${self.triggers.encoded_replication_config}'"
  }
}

locals {
  replication_config = jsonencode({
    "Role" : role_arn,
    "Rules" : [
      {
        "ID": "replication-id"
        "Status" : "Enabled",
        "Priority" : 1,
        "DeleteMarkerReplication" : { "Status" : "Disabled" },
        "Filter" : { "Prefix" : "" },
        "Destination" : {
          "Bucket" : replica_bucket_arn,
          "ReplicationTime" : {
            "Status" : "Enabled",
            "Time" : {
              "Minutes" : 15
            }
          },
          "Metrics" : {
            "Status" : "Enabled",
            "EventThreshold" : {
              "Minutes" : 15
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

While this works alright for a few buckets, in case of a large no. of S3 buckets (say 500), because the replication config is not stored in tfstate, the local-exec to update replication config is executed every time for all the buckets on *terraform apply*, even when a completely new bucket is created.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could suggest other workarounds for this problem.